# Amazon ec2 illegal instruction Asterisk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, asterisk

I am building an Asterisk server using an ec2 instance from the Amazon AWS Service.
Now I have the following problem.

I need to say, this only occurs sometimes, not always!

When I create an instance through the Amazon Cli AMI, it works in most of the cases, but sometimes I get the error "Illegal Instruction".

```
# asterisk -cvvvvvvvvvvvvr
Illegal Instruction
```

When this occurs, the programs like Asterisk don't work. 
I try restarting the processes, but the error "Illegal Instruction" keeps showing up.

How can I avoid this? 
Is this an error that more people have with the Amazon Cli AMI.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Messages like “illegal instruction” typically indicate that the application is trying to tell the CPU to do something that it can’t do.

It is typically the result of running a binary compiled for a different processor variant that is actually being used.

Comment: Hi Reza, We created the instance from an image file. While we created the image file, the Asterisk process was working fine.

Comment: That is typically the result of running a binary compiled for a different processor variant that is actually being used.

Comment: Ok Thank you, we have fixed it now by rebooting the server and taking a break before going to the next steps. This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you building for ec2, you should disable SSE and other optimizatins via make menuconfig

Unfortanly most images created by "expert" who don't know much about asterisk and linux.

Best solution - setup simple  bash script which download and build asterisk every time instance start. That way you have all optimization and no problem with instance cpu.

If you are using asterisk in short slot - solution is rebuild it with turned off optimizations. In this case better use 64bit instances.

Answer (score 0):

To help people that have the same error.
Have fixed the error by **rebuilding Asterisk** with the **build_native** option off in the menu selection.

This fixes the error every single time. 
Have tested it multiple times!